# How to use adb using bluetooth?

Tags: android, networking, bluetooth, adb, tcp

I am currently using an API 18 (Jelly Bean) device, and it does not support ADB over Bluetooth by default (No option available in developers option for wireless debugging) I have to connect my device with my Laptop using Bluetooth Personal Area Network which is Bluetooth tethering of my phone. Can anyone help me with starting a TCP open port my phone so that I can connect ADB using the `adb tcpip "open_port_no"` and `adb connect <phone_ip_address>:open_port_no` commands?
I have already tried some apps from playstore to do so but they all failed.

Comment: Please anyone reply..??!!!

Answer (score 7):

You need to enable the TCP port first by connecting a USB cable to your phone and setting it from the console on your PC/Mac:

```
adb tcpip 4455
```

Now turn on the Bluetooth on your phone and enable tethering.

You need to use the IP address of your phone. **It will most likely be 192.168.44.1 since this is the default.** If not:

You can get this using a few methods depending on your computer type:

```
 ifconfig
 ipconfig /all
 route | grep default
```

Then connect to your phone from your computer using:

```
 adb connect 192.168.44.1:4455
```

You should get a response:

```
 connected to 192.168.44.1:5555
```

This works perfectly for me. Sorry for the late response :) I was just looking for the same thing and happened upon the solution. Sharing is caring.